# Cannot use object of type MysqlResultSet

Tags: php, mysql

i had a problem in php install.php file
Cannot use object of type MysqlResultSet
i dont know why is my code not working

and this is my code

```
    $this->provider->executeQuery('INSERT INTO perfect SET type="kings", name="%s", email="%s", points="%s", p_date="%s"',
                                  array($get_players['name'], $get_players['email'], 0, date('Y.m.d'))
      );
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

full code is

```
public function _isperfect()
{
    // attackers
    $count_attackers  = 0;
    $attackers_points = 0;
    $attackers = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='attackers' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $attackers->next( ) )
    {
        $attackers_points = $attackers->row['points'];
        $count_attackers++;
    }

    if($count_attackers < 3)
    {
        $attackers_points = 0;
    }

    $get_players = $this->provider->fetchResultSet('SELECT name, email, attack_points FROM p_players WHERE attack_points > %s', array($attackers_points));
    while ( $get_players->next( ) )
    {
        $get_att = $this->provider->fetchRow("SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='attackers' && email='". $get_players->row['email'] ."'");
        if($get_att != NULL && $get_att['points'] < $get_players->row['attack_points'])
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE type="attackers" && email="'. $get_players->row['email'] .'"');
        }
        if($get_att['points'] < $get_players->row['attack_points'] || $get_att == null)
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('INSERT INTO perfect SET type="attackers", name="%s", email="%s", points="%s", p_date="%s"',
                                          array($get_players->row['name'], $get_players->row['email'], $get_players->row['attack_points'], date('Y.m.d'))
              );

        }
    }


    $att = 0;
    $attack = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='attackers' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $attack->next( ) )
    {
        $att = $attack->row['points'];
    }
    $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE points < %s && type="attackers"', array($att));

    // end attackers


    // defenders
    $count_defenders  = 0;
    $defenders_points = 0;
    $defenders = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='defenders' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $defenders->next( ) )
    {
        $defenders_points = $defenders->row['points'];
        $defenders_points++;
    }

    if($count_defenders < 3)
    {
        $defenders_points = 0;
    }

    $get_players = $this->provider->fetchResultSet('SELECT name, email, defense_points FROM p_players WHERE defense_points > %s', array($defenders_points));
    while ( $get_players->next( ) )
    {
        $get_def = $this->provider->fetchRow("SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='defenders' && email='". $get_players->row['email'] ."'");
        if($get_def != NULL && $get_def['points'] < $get_players->row['defense_points'])
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE type="defenders" && email="'. $get_players->row['email'] .'"');
        }
        if($get_def['points'] < $get_players->row['defense_points'] || $get_def == null)
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('INSERT INTO perfect SET type="defenders", name="%s", email="%s", points="%s", p_date="%s"',
                                          array($get_players->row['name'], $get_players->row['email'], $get_players->row['defense_points'], date('Y.m.d'))
              );
        }
    }


    $def = 0;
    $defend = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='defenders' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $defend->next( ) )
    {
        $def = $defend->row['points'];
    }
    $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE points < %s && type="defenders"', array($def));

    // end defenders


    // empires
    $count_empires  = 0;
    $empires_points = 0;
    $empires = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='empires' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $empires->next( ) )
    {
        $empires_points = $empires->row['points'];
        $count_empires++;
    }

    if($count_empires < 3)
    {
        $empires_points = 0;
    }

    $get_players = $this->provider->fetchResultSet('SELECT name, email, total_people_count FROM p_players WHERE total_people_count > %s', array($empires_points));
    while ( $get_players->next( ) )
    {
        $get_emp = $this->provider->fetchRow("SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='empires' && email='". $get_players->row['email'] ."'");
        if($get_emp != NULL && $get_emp['points'] < $get_players->row['total_people_count'])
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE type="empires" && email="'. $get_players->row['email'] .'"');
        }
        if($get_emp['points'] < $get_players->row['total_people_count'] || $get_emp == null)
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('INSERT INTO perfect SET type="empires", name="%s", email="%s", points="%s", p_date="%s"',
                                          array($get_players->row['name'], $get_players->row['email'], $get_players->row['total_people_count'], date('Y.m.d'))
              );
        }
    }


    $emp = 0;
    $empir = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='empires' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $empir->next( ) )
    {
        $emp = $empir->row['points'];
    }

    $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE points < %s && type="empires"', array($emp));

    // end empires

    // looters
    $count_looters  = 0;
    $looters_points = 0;
    $looters = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='looters' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $looters->next( ) )
    {
        $looters_points = $looters->row['points'];
        $count_looters++;
    }

    if($count_looters < 3)
    {
        $looters_points = 0;
    }

    $get_players = $this->provider->fetchResultSet('SELECT name, email, thief_points FROM p_players WHERE thief_points > %s', array($looters_points));
    while ( $get_players->next( ) )
    {
        $get_loo = $this->provider->fetchRow("SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='looters' && email='". $get_players->row['email'] ."'");
        if($get_loo != NULL && $get_loo['points'] < $get_players->row['thief_points'])
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE type="looters" && email="'. $get_players->row['email'] .'"');
        }
        if($get_loo['points'] < $get_players->row['thief_points'] || $get_loo == null)
        {
            $this->provider->executeQuery('INSERT INTO perfect SET type="looters", name="%s", email="%s", points="%s", p_date="%s"',
                                          array($get_players->row['name'], $get_players->row['email'], $get_players->row['thief_points'], date('Y.m.d'))
              );
        }
    }


    $loo = 0;
    $loote = $this->provider->fetchResultSet( "SELECT points FROM perfect WHERE type='looters' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3");
    while ( $loote->next( ) )
    {
        $loo = $loote->row['points'];
    }
    $this->provider->executeQuery('DELETE FROM perfect WHERE points < %s && type="looters"', array($loo));

    // end looters


    // kings
    $end_server          = $this->provider->fetchRow( "SELECT win_pid, game_over FROM `g_settings`");
    $end_server_player   = $this->provider->fetchRow( 'SELECT `name`,`email` FROM  `p_players` WHERE id='.$end_server['win_pid'].' ');
    if($end_server_player != null)
    {
        $this->provider->executeQuery('INSERT INTO perfect SET type="kings", name="%s", email="%s", points="%s", p_date="%s"',
                                      array($get_players['name'], $get_players['email'], 0, date('Y.m.d'))
          );
    }
}
```